# SQL query: total people living in each province

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

I am using PostgreSQL and Windows.

I have an SQL query issue. The table diagram:

[image: table diagram]

I am having difficulty trying to understand this scenario:

Return the list of provinces alphabetically ordered, and the total count of personnel living in each province where there are at least 5 personnel living in it.

The answer should look something like this:

[image: result]

How can I write a query for this?

Comment: Queries that are of the form "please write some code for me" are not ideal here, even if you will get the odd answer that is willing to do that. Broadly readers like to see that you have tried something. You'll know this is a `SELECT` query, so that's a start. If you have some test data in a real database that helps a lot - since you can try some experimental queries yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see this as being a join between the `Province` and `Personnel` tables:

```sql
SELECT pv.Code, pv.Name, COUNT(pl.PersonnelID) AS "Total Personnel"
FROM Province pv
LEFT JOIN Personnel pl
    ON pl.CountryOfOrigin = pv.CountryID
GROUP BY pv.Code, pn.Name;
```

Note that I am including the province code in the query, as perhaps two provinces might occasionally share the same name.  If not, then you may remove the code and use the structure of your current output table.